# Playing hi-quality youtube videos seamlessly Is it possible at all on android?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api

I have googled and googled on this. I cannot seem to find a way of seamlessly playing video in high quality from youtube.

I have tried so far:
Using a webview with the following:

```
    htmlstring.append("<iframe title='YouTube video player' class='youtube-player' type='text/html' width='590px' height='370px' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/");
    htmlstring.append(wYouTubeId+"?autoplay='1' frameborder='0' allowFullScreen='1'></iframe>");
    htmlstring.append("</center></body></html>");           
    webView.loadData(htmlstring.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

This has been working fine, but not on android 4 for some reason (Note & S3 tested)

So i tried this object version:

```
    htmlstring.append("<object width='480' height='330'><param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/"+wYouTubeId+"?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0'>");   
    htmlstring.append("</param><param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param>");
    htmlstring.append("<param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'></param>");
    htmlstring.append("<embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/"+wYouTubeId+"?version=3&amp;hl=pt_BR&amp;rel=0' ");
    htmlstring.append("type='application/x-shockwave-flash' width='480' height='330' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' /></object>");
    webView.loadData(htmlstring.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

No joy there either. It just spins and then gives out a blue lego block. These methods work on Android 2.2 though.

Then i tried this:

```
mp.setDataSource("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+wYouTubeId);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

I have also tried this with a direct rtsp link found in the channel feed but they are of way too low quality to be usable. How can i tell which version is the high quality one as I am seeing loads of them.

I have also tried doing it manually with a VideoView but i get the same problem.

Lots of people recommend using this:

```
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fileListItem.getLink())));
```

But that is not an option, unless there is a way to launch the youtube app in landscape seamlessly without text. (Our client does not want it).

It seems to me strange that Android is a google system, Youtube is a google system yet on iOS (even iOS6!) it seems that it was easy to implement the video. 
Why is it so hard to play a "google" video on "google" android??

Answer (score 0):

This will be the best approach when it's publicly released: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/120/ (I can't share any specific dates regarding its availability).

In the meantime, using the  embed will probably get you closest to what you want. What specifically was broken about it when you tried it? Could you [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Defect%20Report%29) with a description of the problem, including the video ids you tried to play back?

Comment: will this EVER be released though? it's taking forever! With the embedded webview there's no way to remove the fullscreen button (that doesn't work anyways). Also it's very buggy in many different devices.